# Count pixels of color in JES (Jython)

Tags: python, jes

I am trying to pull the overall pixel count of the R, G, B, Black, & White values in a premade picture. This picture has 100 Red, 100 Green, 100 Blue, 100 Black, and 100 white.

I have started with my code, but for some reason it seems as if my code is only counting 1 pixel.. 
Jython has predefined 16 colors, so I am using the red, blue, green datatypes.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
 file = pickAFile( )
 pic = makePicture( file )

  pxRed = 0
  pxGreen = 0
  pxBlue = 0
  numR = 0
  numG = 0
  numB = 0

 printNow("Now let's count some pixels...")

 for px in getPixels( pic ):
   r = getRed(px)
   g = getGreen(px)
   b = getBlue(px)
   If px is (255,0,0): #error here
     numR += 1
     printNow("You have " + numR + " red pixels")
 show(pic)
```

unsure why this is not working..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get the colors separately.
You can go with the `getColor(px)`-function.

Furthermore there is no function `printNow(str)` in python. So as long as this function is not part of any package you use, you need to use `print(str)`

The function `getColor` returns an Object like `Color(255,0,0)` to compare this, you can't just compare against a Tuple but want to use the `distance` function from JES. Therefore you need to make a `Color` object for comparison like `red = makeColor(255,0,0)` and compare against this. The possible output from the `distance` function ranges from 0 (exact same color) to ~441.7 (black compared with white).

So try it like this:

```
red = makeColor(255,0,0)
green = makeColor(0,255,0)
blue = makeColor(0,0,255)

for px in getPixels( pic ):
   color = getColor(px)
   if distance(color, red) == 0:
       numR += 1
   elif distance(color, green) == 0:
       numG += 1
   elif distance(color, blue) == 0:
       numB += 1

print("You have " + numR + " red pixels")
print("You have " + numG + " green pixels")
print("You have " + numB + " blue pixels")
```

I guessed you need the number in total after counting. If you want to output the number while iterating, just put the print back in the loop.

Comment: Here is the issue I am running into now, my code stops at    if color == (255,0,0):

returning: The error value is: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getRed'
Attribute not found.
You are trying to access a part of the object that doesn't exist.

Kind of unsure what this means.

Comment: Sorry, I oversaw, that the getColor function does not return a tuple but an Object. I updated my answer. For further information you could have a look at this [link](http://www.cs.bu.edu/courses/cs101b1/jes)